# What is one effective way for setting up DNS forwarding between GCE and AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, vpn, google-compute-engine

I've set up a VPN tunnel to allow my GCE services to access some legacy resources sitting in AWS; it turns out that accessing some of these legacy resources (ie, RDS servers) requires me to be able to dynamically forward DNS. That is, if I want the connection to go over the vpn instead of the open internet.

What is the easiest method to do this - would setting up a couple of unbound dns servers do the trick, for example? If it is the correct solution, which network would they have to sit in - the aws or gce one?

Comment: You can setup a VPN tunnel across GCE VPN gateway and your AWS VPC where the RDS instance is located. You should be able to access RDS from GCE to connect to the db.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the VPN tunnel offerings from GCE - do they offer dynamic dns forwarding features?

Comment: You shouldn't need to "forward" DNS.  The hostname of a private RDS instance should still resolve to the private IP regardless of where you look it up.  Perhaps you have a different example?

Comment: The hostname of a private RDS instance is not visible publicly - GCE instances will never be able to resolve it

Comment: @blueberryfields I haven't tried VPN Gateway in GCE side but, but before answering I did a quick look at the doc in the following link https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/creating-vpns

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be an easy method to get DNS forwarding to work properly across the VPN.

The easiest workable solution involves setting up a small EC2 machine as a proxy (eg. - use nginx) and referencing that machine by ip address from GCE, instead of using aws's internal machine names. An alternative would be to set up an EC2 machine as a dedicated DNS server and referencing that machine from GCE machines directly. [Neither of these are satisfying solutions - I'm open to other alternatives]

These solutions generally work for any case where you're looking to avoid making connections over the public internet into aws machines.